# Akka stream not processing all the lines from my CSV file

Tags: scala, csv, akka, akka-stream, throttling

I am using Akka stream to process a CSV file containing 1839 lines. I have added counters to count the number of lines processed.

Here is my source, I have made sure that each line in the input file is less than 700 chars.

```
case class ParsedLine(input: String, field1: String, field2: String, field3: String)


val counter0 = new AtomicInteger()
val counter1 = new AtomicInteger()

val lineSource = FileIO
    .fromPath(Paths.get(InputFile))
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 1024, allowTruncation = true))
    .map { l =>
      counter0.incrementAndGet()
      l.utf8String
    }

 val parseLine = Flow[String].map { l =>
     val words = l.split(",")
     ParsedLine(l, words(0), words(1), words(2))
 }
```

This source is processed as follows, corresponding to every line in the source there should be a processed line in the output.

```
val done = lineSource
    .via(parseLine)
    .to(Sink.foreach(_.input))
    .run()


  done.onComplete {
    case Success(_) =>
      println("Counter0 " + counter0.get())
      println("Counter1 " + counter1.get())
      system.terminate()
    case Failure(e) =>
      println(e.getLocalizedMessage)
      system.terminate()
  }
```

The interesting thing is the counters are printing as follows & the each time I am getting different numbers. If I remove the `.to(Sink.foreach(_.input))` line I am getting the counts as 1839.

```
Counter0 1445
Counter1 1667
```

First of all I expect Counter0 to have a higher value than Counter1 because Counter0 comes in a stage before Counter1, I expect all the lines to be processed and counters should have printed the total number of lines 1839.

Any idea what is going on in this case ? Is akka stream dropping items in between ?

Comment: what is that `counter0` and `counter1`? Also as I am assuming your counting for `countrer1` is happening after `parseLine`, what is your `parseLine`?

Comment: Also, why are you using `case _` instead of checking for both success and failures in your `onComplete`? What if the stream encountered a bad line and failed while processing?

Comment: @sarveshseri  I have updated the question with counter initialisation & parseLine. If stream encounter a bad line then won't it throw some exception ?

Comment: If stream encounters a bad line, you'll have a failed `Future` in your `done`. That's why you should check for success or failure in your `onComplete`. Also errors within the stream can be handled differently depending on a supervision strategy if you need to.

Comment: Ok, what can be a bad line ? I have added both success and failure caes, didn't get eny error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually not waiting for the stream to finish.

You are attatching the `Sink.foreach(...)` using `to` which drops the processing details of `Sink.foreach` stage and keeps only the processing stage of the earlier stage.

Also, keep in mind that you are doing the same at every step (`via`, `map`, `via` and then `to`). So, you are only keeping track of the processing stage of first graph step which was created by `FileIO.from(...)`. This means that you are only waiting to read the full file but not for any of the subsequent processing steps.

You just need to preserve the results of both and wait for both of them to finish.

```scala
val stream =
 lineSource
   .via(parseLine)
   .toMat(Sink.foreach(_.input))(Keep.both)

val resultFutures: (Future[IOResult], Future[Done]) = stream.run()

val resultsFuture = Future.sequence(List(resultFutures._1, resultFutures._2))

resultsFuture.onComplete {
  case Success(List(ioResult, done)) =>
    println(ioResult)
    println(done)
    println(counter0.get())
    actorSystem.terminate()
  case Failure(e) =>
    println(e.getLocalizedMessage)
    actorSystem.terminate()
}
```

Or, you can choose to keep track of just the last processing stage (which is `Sink.foreach(...)` in this case)

```scala
val stream =
  lineSource
    .via(parseLine)
    .toMat(Sink.foreach(_.input))(Keep.right)

val resuleFuture: Future[Done] = stream.run()

resuleFuture.onComplete({
  case Success(_) =>
    println("Counter0 " + counter0.get())
    actorSystem.terminate()
  case Failure(e) =>
    println(e.getLocalizedMessage)
    actorSystem.terminate()
})
```

Comment: Thanks this works as expected. But I didn't understand how the stream is"keeping track" of its stages. I should read more on this any links to understand it better would be helpful.

Comment: All graph stages can be either materialized or not materialized. The first graph state is materialized by default. Then while adding more steps to the graph, you can choose to materialize them. Almost all (or even all) graph concatenation methods will have two versions; for example - `to` and `toMat`, `via` and `viaMat`. Read more at - https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-composition.html#materialized-values